# Retrieving multiple values inside the Success function and storing them to javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my index file where I want to get the values from the fetch.php.   `$('#loader').html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));` This allows to get all the values and show it inside the div = loader. But I want to store individual return values to javascript values.

```
     $.post("fetch.php?url="+$('#url').val(), {}, function(response){
    //var $res=$(response);
    //var title =$res.filter('.title').text();   (not wrking)
    //$('#title').val(title);
    $('#loader').html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));              
    $('.images img').hide();                                      
    $('#load').hide();
    $('img#1').fadeIn();
    $('#cur_image').val(1);
     });
}); 
   <input type="hidden" name="cur_image" id="cur_image" />
   <div id="loader">

  <div align="center" id="load" style="display:none"><img src="load.gif" /></div>

  </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="title" id="title" />

 (e.g. I want to store the title value from fetch.php to this hidden field)
**fetch.php**
                  <div class="info">

        <label class="title">
            <?php echo @$url_title[0]; ?>
        </label>
        <br clear="all" />
        <label class="url">
            <?php  echo substr($url ,0,35); ?>
        </label>
        <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
        <label class="desc">
            <?php  echo @$tags['description']; ?>
        </label>
        <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />

        <label style="float:left"><img src="prev.png" id="prev" alt="" /><img src="next.png" id="next" alt="" /></label>

        <label class="totalimg">
            Total <?php echo $k?> images
        </label>
        <br clear="all" />

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode` in PHP, and `$.parseJSON` in jQuery like so:

```
$.post("fetch.php?url="+$('#url').val(), {}, function(response) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
    if (result.success) {
       var title = result.data.title;
       ...
    }
});
```

In your PHP you simply output something like:

```
json_encode(
  array(
    'success' => true,
    'data' => array(
               'title' => 'yourTitle',
               'description' => 'yourDescription'
              )
  )
 );
```

**Another note**

Please don't use @. If you aren't sure that index exists use correct validation, for example:

```
<?php if (is_array($url_title) && isset($url_title[0])): ?>
    <label class="title"><?php echo $url_title[0]; ?></label>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or

```
<label class="title"><?=is_array($url_title) && isset($url_title[0]) ? $url_title[0] : ''?></label>
```

**EDIT:**

Added extra indentation and extended the data array to make it more clear to the OP.

Comment: Okay thanks. In my php file, I am echoing 4 values so for each I should use json. e.g json_encode('title'=>'my title'), json_encode('description'=>'my_description').

Comment: No, just add them to the array that you pass to `json_encode` - so `array('title' => 'your title', 'description' => 'your description');`. I updated my answer to reflect this.